# Fluent Validation Boolean field must be required

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

The below code is not giving me error Saying  'isContinuous' is required field.

```
public class Bond
{
  public bool isContinuous { get; set; }
}

public class BondValidator : AbstractValidator<Bond>
{
    public BondValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(model => model.isContinuous).NotNull().WithMessage("'is Continous' is required field.").Must(x => x == false || x == true);
            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bool` is a value type, it always is not null. One option is to change the type to be nullable value type - `bool?`:

```cs
public class Bond
{
    public bool? isContinuous { get; set; }
}
```

Then the null check will make sense.

Alternatively you can try using [`required` modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/required) (available since C# 11), but it should result in error on the binder/deserializer level before the fluent validation.

Read more:

- [Value types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types)
- [Nullable value types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)

Comment: Your solution was crisp, Thanks